# DataType of Pandas Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,2, None), (1,2,3)])
print(index.get_level_values(2))
```

gives

> Int64Index([nan, 3.0], dtype='float64')

However, I would like to get

> Int64Index([nan, 3], dtype='object')

That is, Pandas should not automatically change the data type. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert level values to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.astype.html), [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) it by `.` and [`get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html) first value. Then create new [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html):

```
#change multiindex
new = zip(index.get_level_values(0),
          index.get_level_values(1),
          index.get_level_values(2).astype(str).str.split('.').str.get(0))


new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new)
print (new_index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[1], [2], [u'3', u'nan']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0]])

print(new_index.get_level_values(2))
Index([u'nan', u'3'], dtype='object')
```