# get the dtype of a pandas multiindex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I find the `dtype` of a `MultiIndex` in pandas without printing out all the values (this happens if you type `df.index`, for example). I just want to know the names of the indices and their types.

Ex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.arange(100000), "b": np.arange(100000)[::-1]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.arange(100000), np.arange(100000)[::-1]], names=["i1", "i2"]))
```

doing:

```
df.index
```

will take some time to actually print, for a large df that's too long.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909457/datatype-of-pandas-multiindex?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use get_level_values:

```
df.index.get_level_values(0).dtype
dtype('int64')
```

and

```
df.index.get_level_values(1).dtype
dtype('int64')
```

For names use:

```
df.index.names
FrozenList(['i1', 'i2'])
```

Answer (score 10):

#### pandas >= 1.3 [est]

Coming soon to a distro near you, you [`MultiIndex.dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.dtypes.html#pandas.MultiIndex.dtypes) will soon be available:

```
df.index.dtypes

i1    int64
i2    int64
dtype: object
```

---

For older versions, if your index is not too large, you can first convert to a frame using `to_frame`, then query the dtypes:

```
df.index.to_frame().dtypes

i1    int64
i2    int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on the great answer by @Scott Boston, I wrote this function for a quick check for the dtypes of all the levels of multiindex dfs and just thought I'd share:

```
def index_level_dtypes(df):
    return [f"{df.index.names[i]}: {df.index.get_level_values(n).dtype}"
            for i, n in enumerate(df.index.names)]
```