# converting type of pandas columns under MultiIndex

Tags: pandas

I have something like

```
>>> df
      user1 user2 param
                   0             1      2
                   a      x      d      a 
    0  2     6     0      1      0      0
    1  4     13    0      0      0      3
    2  21    76    2      0      1      0
```

Note that `user1` and `user2` are at the same level as `param` (side effect of merging):

```
>>> df.columns.get_level_values(0)
Index(['user1','user2','param','param','param','param'], dtype='object')

>>> df.columns.get_level_values(1)
Index(['','',0,0,1,2], dtype='object')
```

I want to convert all under `param` to floats, but keep `user1` and `user2` as integers. I've checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091365/get-the-dtype-of-a-pandas-multiindex) but I'm not sure how that translates to *setting* **column** dtypes.

EDIT:

Generator code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user1':[2,4,21,21],'user2':[6,13,76,76],'param1':[0,2,0,1],'param2':['x','a','a','d'],'count':[1,3,2,1]}, columns=['user1','user2','param1','param2','count'])
df = df.set_index(['user1','user2','param1','param2'])
df = df.unstack([2,3]).sort_index(axis=1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user1':[2,5,21],'user2':[6,18,76]})
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, [''],['']])
final_df = df2.merge(df, on=['user1','user2'], how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Can you provide a DataFrame generator?

Comment: Hi @gonzalomr I added some generator code above, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not able to provide a tested solution for you specific DataFrame as I am not sure of its exact structure.

But on a MultiIndex DataFrame (and any other) you can perform changes on individual columns of a DataFrame using the underlying attributes of the Series that compose them. In this case you can change the dtypes of all columns under param by filtering by `series.name` as follows.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(float) if 'param' in x.name else x)
```

The way that pandas constructs MultiIndex names is by creating a tuple with the different levels, so a `contains` operation over it gives you the desired columns.

**EDIT:**

I have tested the code in your sample DataFrame and it works.

Seeing your comment. If you want to manually access and modify each column you can do it with the `astype` method by itself.

```
final_df['count'] = final_df['count'].astype(float)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about `contains` though...I added some generator code above. I was thinking of adding every single one of those series and doing it manually, but in the full version (this is a sample one), there are number of those columns and it's best if I can just refer to them under one name (in this case, the name `count`).

Comment: It does depends if all the columns that are named in the same way do need to be of the same dtype. In the affirmative case this can be used without problem else other criteria can be used to target your desired columns. If the addition is a manual check the answer eddit.